# error de rango no detectado se excedió. Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de poner un mensaje de error en el input con id = "r" en el caso de que no se cumplan con las condiciones de cada variable. De manera que el usuario se vea obligado a corregir los datos, para entregar finalmente un resultado. Entonces lo que necesito es que por cada validación en caso de que se cumpla se muestre el mensaje de error en el input.  la situación que es soy bastante nueva en programación, y se esta generando el error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Y la verdad no se como corregirlo.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>ttt</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cell-md-4">
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header clear">Altura1</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="htx" value="35" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Altura" placeholder="Ingrese la altura" onchange="updatehtx();">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header clear">Altura2</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="hrx" value="1.5" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Altura" placeholder="Ingrese la altura" onchange="updatehrx();">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Frecuencia</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="frecuencia" value="150" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Frecuencia [MHz]" placeholder="Ingrese la frecuencia" onchange="updatefreq();">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
 <div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Seleccione Entorno</div>
<div class="card-content p-4">
<form>
<select name="Entorno" id="Entorno">
<option disabled selected value="-1">Elija una opci&oacute;n</option>
<option value="ciudades">Cuidades pequeñas y medianas</option>
<option value="metropolitana">&Aacute;rea metropolitana</option>
<option value="suburbano">Ambiente suburbano</option>
<option value="rural">&Aacute;rea rural</option>
</select> 
</form>
<button id="calcular" >Calcular</button> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>                  
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Resultado</div>
 <div class="card-content p-3">
  <input id="r" type="text" data-role="input" data-prepend="Resultado : " data-append="dB" disabled>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>                     
 </div>
 </div>
<script>
var calcular = document.getElementById("calcular");
function updatehrx(hr){
              
if(hr < 1 || hr > 10){
alert("Modificar valor");
return "Error";
 }
 document.getElementById('r').value = updatehrx();
 }                             
              
function updatehtx(ht){
if(ht < 30 || ht > 200){
alert("Modificar valor ");
return "Error";           
 }
 document.getElementById('r').value = updatehtx();
 }               
 
function updatefreq(freq){
if(freq < 150 || freq > 1500){
alert("Modificar valor");
}
document.getElementById('r').value = updatefreq();
}   



// accion boton      
document.querySelector('#calcular').addEventListener('click', () =>{
  
   
var hr = parseFloat(document.getElementById("hrx").value);
var ht = parseFloat(document.getElementById("htx").value);
var freq = parseFloat(document.getElementById("frecuencia").value);        
   
updatehrx(hr)
updatehtx(ht)
updatefreq(freq)         

if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "seleccione"){
alert("Debes seleccionar el entorno")
} 

else if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "ciudades") {
function ciudadesPyM() {
 return 1; 
}
 document.getElementById('r').value = ciudadesPyM();
}

else if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "metropolitana") {
            
function metropolitana(){
return 2;
}
document.getElementById('r').value = metropolitana();
}
            
else if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "suburbano") {
function suburbano() {
return 3;
}
document.getElementById('r').value = suburbano();
}
 
else if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "rural") {

function rural() { 
return 4;
}
document.getElementById('r').value = rural();
}   
                                  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fijate que en las 3 primeras funciones estas generando una recursividad osea creas la funcion y la llamas inmediatamente , ya con 1 funcion asi alcanza para que se desborde la pila que es el error que tenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada, decirte que, tienes que organizar mejor tu código, esto te va a ayudar a entender con más claridad lo que quieres hacer y los posibles errores que pueda lanzar.
El error que muestra, se trata de la llamada a una función de manera consecutiva e innecesaria, haciendo que la pila se pierda.
El error es el siguiente:

```js
//* Declaramos como se llamara nuestra función: updatefreq
//! Asignamos un parametro llamado freq, este parametro tiene un valor unico, no es lo mismo que la variable declarada llamada "Freq", ya que es un contexto diferente y a esta se le asigna el valor dentro de los parentesis de la función cuando la llamamos: updatefreq(valor) ejemplo: updatefreq(1)

function updatefreq(freq) {

  //*Aqui se declara una condición que tendra como función mostrar una alerta
  if (freq < 150 || freq > 1500) {
    alert("Modificar valor");
  }

  //? En esta sección asignamos al input con id "r" un valor
  //? El valor que tendra será el resultado que retorne la función updatefreq()
  document.getElementById("r").value = updatefreq();
}

//! Si nos ponemos a pensar un poco, ¿Qué valor tendrá finalmente el input "r" si la funcion no retorna ningún valor y nisiquiera le estamos asignando un parametro?¿Cuál será el valor de ese parametro si no es asignado?
//! Esta funcion es un bucle infinito

//!
  Paso 1. Cambio el valor del input frecuencia
  Paso 2. Se llama a la función updatefreq()
  Paso 3. la función toma un parametro sin ningun valor
  Paso 4. La función asigna un valor a r que tiene como asignación una función, este paso hace que regreses al paso 2.
 !//

// * algo muy disinto seria esto

function updatefreq(a = freq.value){
  if(a < 150 || a > 1500){
    alert("modificar valor")
  }
  document.getElementById.value = a
}

// Lo que sucede en esa función, es que a nuestro parametro llamado a le asignamos un valor automaticamente si no se le es asignado al llamar esta función
// Podemos llamar a la funcion de este modo updatefreq() o updatefreq(tuvalor)
```

***Y finalmente, lo que quieres realizar es esto:***

```js
//*Todos los elementos disponibles en nuestro formulario
const altura = document.querySelector("#htx");
const altura2 = document.querySelector("#hrx");
const frecuencia = document.querySelector("#frecuencia");
const entorno = document.querySelector("#Entorno");
const btncalcular = document.querySelector("#calcular");
const resultado = document.querySelector("#r");

const updatehrx = (hr = altura2.value) => {
  let z = hr;
  if (hr < 1 || hr > 10) {
    alert("Modificar valor");
    z = "Error";
  }
  resultado.value = z;
};

const updatehtx = (ht = altura.value) => {
  let z = ht;
  if (ht < 30 || ht > 200) {
    alert("Modificar valor");
    z = "Error";
  }
  resultado.value = z;
};
const updatefreq = (freq = frecuencia.value) => {
  let z;
  if (freq < 150 || freq > 1500) {
    alert("Modifica tu valor");
    z = "Error";
  }
  resultado.value = z;
};
btncalcular.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let hr = parseFloat(altura2.value);
  let ht = parseFloat(altura.value);
  let freq = parseFloat(frecuencia.value);

  updatehrx(hr);
  updatehtx(ht);
  updatefreq(freq);

  if (entorno.value === "seleccione") {
    alert("Debes seleccionar el entorno");
  } else if (entorno.value === "ciudades") {
    let ciudadesPyM = () => {
      return 1;
    };
    resultado.value = ciudadesPyM();
  } else if (entorno === "metropolitana") {
    let metropolitana = () => {
      return 2;
    };
    resultado.value = metropolitana();
  } else if (entorno.value === "suburbano") {
    let suburbano = () => {
      return 3;
    };
    resultado.value = suburbano();
  } else if (entorno.value === "rural") {
    let rural = () => {
      return 4;
    };
    resultado.value = rural();
  }
});
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>ttt</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cell-md-4">
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header clear">Altura1</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="htx" value="35" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Altura" placeholder="Ingrese la altura" onchange="updatehtx();">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header clear">Altura2</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="hrx" value="1.5" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Altura" placeholder="Ingrese la altura" onchange="updatehrx();">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Frecuencia</div>
<div class="card-content p-3">
<input id="frecuencia" value="150" type="text" data-role="materialinput" data-label="Frecuencia [MHz]" placeholder="Ingrese la frecuencia" onchange="updatefreq();">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
 <div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Seleccione Entorno</div>
<div class="card-content p-4">
<form>
<select name="Entorno" id="Entorno">
<option disabled selected value="-1">Elija una opci&oacute;n</option>
<option value="ciudades">Cuidades pequeñas y medianas</option>
<option value="metropolitana">&Aacute;rea metropolitana</option>
<option value="suburbano">Ambiente suburbano</option>
<option value="rural">&Aacute;rea rural</option>
</select> 
</form>
<button id="calcular" >Calcular</button> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>                  
<div class="row">
<div class="cell">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header">Resultado</div>
 <div class="card-content p-3">
  <input id="r" type="text" data-role="input" data-prepend="Resultado : " data-append="dB" disabled>
</div>
  </div>
  </div>                     
 </div>
 </div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Te invito a documentarte más mediante este enlace
***[funciones y parametros](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Funciones)***

Comment: muchas gracias!